# Read file name in numerical order as opposed to ASCI ordering using glob?

Tags: python, sorting, ascii, glob, numeric

I have a list of files named as follows:

```
file1.png
file2.png
...
file9.png
file10.png
file11.png
...
file99.png
file100.png
file101.png
...
```

When I read the directories using this code:

```
images = [file for file in glob.glob(image_dir + '*')]
```

I get an output which orders the file names as follows:

```
[image_dir/file1.png
image_dir/file10.png
image_dir/file100.png
image_dir/file101.png
... 
image_dir/file109.png
image_dir/file11.png
image_dir/file110.png
...
image_dir/file119.png
image_dir/file12.png
image_dir/file120.png
...]
```

How do I get the files in proper numerical order?

Comment: use `sorted`, easier

Comment: Do all the file names start with "file"? Regardless, do they _all_ end with a number?

Comment: Side-note: Relying on *any* specific ordering in the output of Python's `glob.glob` is a mistake, one that has caused errors [in numerous scientific studies](https://www.vice.com/en_us/article/zmjwda/a-code-glitch-may-have-caused-errors-in-more-than-100-published-studies). So even if you wanted ASCIIbetical sorting, you need to explicitly perform the sorting yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using:

```
print(sorted(images, key=lambda x: int(x.split('file')[-1].split('.')[0])))
```